# Why is my ISP provided wireless router is not giving me the Mbps they say?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router

I have a Mikrotik Map 2n wireless router. My ISP is Vectus, a family owned ISP in Huntington Beach, Ca. I was getting 10/3 Mbps or it varied. Now I asked them to bump up the speed to 15/4 Mbps. I ran speed tests and it's telling me I'm only getting at the most 8/4 Mbps, it's been sometimes faster but mostly slower than that speed.

I've been going back and forth with my ISP and they tell me everything is fine on their end and ran test's on my end (from their facility) and said there's no reason why I shouldn't be getting the 15/4 I've been paying for because everything looks fine. I asked them if someone was "stealing" my bandwidth, and they said they couldn't be. They can't possibly think it's my equipment!!

My question is could it be my equipment or could someone in my area tapping in on my bandwidth or could it be some other problem?

Comment: Run ping test with ping command. Also try to trace any destination IP with traceroute command.

Comment: For example,  run `tracert 8.8.8.8` to run a traceroute to Google's DNS server (a really reliable test subject)

Comment: Yahoo tells me the devices that have logged in and they say it's from "Shaver Lake", Ca and I'm in La Mirada, Ca and when I look up the IP address for Shaver Lake it says it's private. I'm not sure how to trace a destination IP with a traceroute command.

Comment: You can run `tracert` by pressing *Win+R*, typing `cmd` and pressing *enter*, and then typing the command.

Comment: It says: do not resolve addresses to hostname

Comment: Did you type the command word for word?

Comment: yes I was trying to let you know what it said in the cmd box but i hit enter instead

Comment: Can you repeat the error it gave?

Comment: maximum number of hops to hostnames , host list: loose source route along  hoset -list (IPv4- only). Trace round -trip path (IPv6 path only).Source path to use (IPv6- only). force using IPv4. force using IPv6.

Comment: sorry i'm so slow

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do:

- You should be able to login to the router and change your WiFi password
- Request a different router from your ISP, since they're providing you a router that you're paying for each month, they should comply and try that option at least.
- Purchase your own Modem/Router that is compatible with your ISP, which gives you a whole bunch of features ISPs normally block on routers they rent out.

Things to consider:

- Advertised speeds are merely that, advertised. ISPs typically have hours during the day when a lot of people are online and service will slow down and that's just the way it is. The important thing is to watch it and make sure it's not all the time.
- Purchasing a Modem/Router will eliminate the monthly cost of the rented out ISP provided router and will give you more control over your LAN. However, its not a guaranteed fix because sometimes its just where you live and what kind of internet you use.
- I personally like to use speedtest.net for my testing of how fast my internet connection speed. Keep in mind, that you need to make sure no other traffic is running on your network, that you're running from a computer or phone, and then run the speed test.

Now, you can try to get into your router and change the WiFi password, because ISPs usually let people have the ability to change passwords and see who is connected to your network, be it wireless or wired.

You will want to open command propmt, and run:

```
    ipconfig /all
```

This is show you all the information about the connected network adapters in your computer. You're looking for the "Default Gateway" from either the Wireless LAN Connection or the Ethernet Local LAN Connection.

Usually, 192.168.1.1 is the default IP address to manage your router, but then you will have to know what the user and password is to get logged in and is sometimes printed on the router. You can also ask your ISP if you're unsure of what the login info is.

Once you make it to this point, we can further try to troubleshoot what you got going on.

Comment: I was thinking about getting another router, I'll have to research and like you said find one that supports my ISP. But what I find odd is that they told me the only way I can change my password is through them.

Comment: And I might add, that the IP:10.122.0.152 is the one that says it's private, and it's different than my ISP, the default Gateway is the private one.

Comment: Happy to help!, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thank you!